# MaterialIcon don't show on react native maps only in android react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image]

I put here my material icon in my mapView but there is no render only android why ?.[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `MaterialIcons` outside of `MapView`